# Raise event if any control has been changed WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, wpf-controls

I want make validation in my WPF application. And the approach I want to use is I want to take custom action if any value of my controls has been changed.

How I can do that suppose I have control like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Box1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Path=Box2,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And If user change the value one of that control I want to create custom action for example **(For my thinking )**

```
private void Window_Controls_Property_Changed(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e){
  if(((Control)sender)=="TextBox1")
    MessageBox.Show("Show message here of validation some control","Attention",MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

I'm still confusing combine the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ValidationRule` with displaying error what I want with MessageBox. I'm still newbie using this kind of features.

I have read many articles about `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ValidationRule` but I'm still don't know how to get the custom action like I said before. And the custom validation may use another textbpx value to validate with the other textbox.

Any helps?..

Comment: This kind of stuff is where you want to approach your solution using MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel). That's where INotifyPropertyChanged really starts to shine. Read more here; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: thanks for a great stuff.. But I have already read many of MVVM Tutorial.. The way I confuse is I want to detect if any kind of my textbox has value changed with one custom action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the handler on the Container that hosts your TextBox's. Like this:

```
<StackPanel TextBox.LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Box1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Path=Box2,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This way the same handler will be used for all TextBox's and you can query e.Source to find out which TextBox triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

for Validation in mvvm you can take IDataErrorInfo. there are examples all over the net.

and if you really whant to do some special action when a property in your viewmodel change, you can simply subscribe to your own viewmodel PropertyChanged event and handle your stuff

Comment: can you give me an example How I can subscribe to my own viewmodel ?

Comment: within your viewmodel ctor simply do: this.PropertyChanged += MyViewmodelPropertyChanged; now when ever a property is changed you will see this in your MyViewmodelPropertyChanged. but for simple validation you should check IDataErrorInfo

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [this block post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/11/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation.aspx) about BindingGroups and validation (and this [related blog post](http://wpfadventures.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/using-bindinggroups-for-greater-control-over-input-validation/)).  They show you how you can validate multiple controls at once using custom validation rules.

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" LostFocus="OnLostFocus"/>
```

Here's an easy way. Validate using the LostFocus Event in WPF

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (thisTextBox.Text == "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Validate!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this if I have only one control.. But If I have many textbox and I don't know what textbox that has already change value How I can do that? Am I have to add `OnLostFocus` to all my textbox since I have many textbox in my page..